# Spring-data-neo4j 4.0.0 repository makes multiple REST calls instead of grouping them

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I'm using Spring-data-neo4j 4.0.0 with Neo4j 2.3.1 and I'm wondering why when I do something like:

> entityRepository.save(Iterable multipleObjects);

it actually does multiple REST calls on Neo4j server:
- POST to create the transaction (done once, ok)
- POST http://host:7474/db/data/transaction/id {"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE..."}]} (**done once per object to save !**)
- POST to commit the transaction (done once, ok)

When it could group all entities creation into one REST POST call (with multiple statements).

I have performances issues with this use case, and I'm wondering if I don't use SDN correctly.

Or maybe this is a known problem that is planned to be improved in a near future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it correctly- it's a known issue and will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: Thank you ! Do you have by any chance a JIRA link to track the advancement of this issue ?

Comment: It only existed on our trello board, I've opened an issue now- https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/103